# Dijkstra algorithm modification with exactly one relaxation on a directed graph where the weights of outgoing edges of a node are the same

Tags: algorithms, graphs, shortest-path, weighted-graphs, dijkstras-algorithm

Consider the standard version of Dijkstra's algorithm on directed graphs. Assume it is known that the input digraph $G = (V, E)$ has the following property: for all $v \in V$ the weight of all outgoing edges $vu$ is the same.

How can one modify Dijkstra's algorithm so that *exactly one relaxation* is done for every vertex $v \in V$? (i. e. decreasing of current minimal path length $d_{v}$ is done exactly once for every $v$).

Comment: This sounds like a simple exercise. Where is it from? What have you tried?

Comment: I'm not really sure I understand the question. The fact is that the standard Dijkstra already guarantees that every time a vertex is selected for expansion, the minimum distance to it has been already computed, i.e., the minimal path length $d_v$ is computed exactly once ...

Answer (score 1):

In each iteration, instead of choosing the node $u$ with smallest $\mathtt{dist}[u]$ in the standard Dijkstra's algorithm, we choose the node $u$ with smallest $\mathtt{dist}[u]+w(u)$, where $w(u)$ is the weight of outgoing edges from $u$.

The proof of the correctness of this modified algorithm is almost the same as [the one](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra%27s_algorithm#Proof_of_correctness) of the standard Dijkstra's algorithm. As shown in the proof for the standard Dijkstra's algorithm, it also holds that for each visited node $v$, $\mathtt{dist}[v]$ is the shortest distance from source to $v$.

Now consider a node $v$. Let $P$ be a shortest path from source to $v$. Suppose $\mathtt{dist}[v]$ is first updated through $u$ (i.e., it is updated to $\mathtt{dist}[u]+w(u)$), and when $\mathtt{dist}[v]$ is first updated, $x$ is the first unvisited node on $P$, then $\mathtt{dist}[x]+w(x)\le w(P)\le \mathtt{dist}[u]+w(u)$, where $w(P)$ is the shortest distance from source to $v$. Also note at this time $u$ is chosen instead of $x$, we have 
$\mathtt{dist}[u]+w(u)\le \mathtt{dist}[x]+w(x)$, hence $\mathtt{dist}[x]+w(x)= w(P)= \mathtt{dist}[u]+w(u)$, i.e., $\mathtt{dist}[v]$ is first updated to the shortest distance from source to $v$, and it will not be updated any more.